# How to pass variable from different class to the main class

Tags: java, android

I want to pass some variables to the main class and do some calculations depend on the user input in the previous interfaces. I've tried to use setters and the getters but the most confusing part is how to use those variable to do the calculation without displaying them in TextView.

```
public class Weight extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    public static AutoCompleteTextView userWeight;
    private Button secondPage;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_weight);

        userWeight =(AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.weight);
        secondPage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.toHeightPage);

        secondPage.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    }

    private void enterWeight(){
        String weight = userWeight.getText().toString().trim();

        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(weight)){
            Toast.makeText(Weight.this,"Please Enter your weight", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return;
    }
```

in this class I want to get the value of the weight and use it in the main class, and here is the main class code.

```
public class Main_Interface extends AppCompatActivity {
    public TextView results;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main__interface);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar1);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        results = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.results);

    }
    public void calculateBMR(){

    }
```

I am going to use the calculation method to use all of the variables in the app to give me the results.

Comment: BroadcastReceiver is your answer! Add a receiver on your main activity and broadcast from your second activity.

Comment: @Badeed  Assuming your main activity launches your weight activity (and height, etc), the way to do this is to launch it using startActivityForResult, and to set a result Intent before finishing the other activity.  This will then be sent to the calling activity in onActivityResult.

Comment: @GabeSechan ? How is BroadcastReceiver overcomplicated..? in terms of process? or matter of how hard it is to code?

Comment: @R.Roh You have to deal with all the boilerplate of registering, unregistering (you don't want to cause a memory leak, do you?), possibly dealing with different UI constraints based on whether the activity is in the foreground or not.  You have limitations to the data allowed to be sent/received by a broadcast receiver.  And  there's a built in method to launch activities and get a result.  Generally broadcast receivers are discouraged except for the case of getting broadcasts from the OS.  (For results, use startActivityForResult.  For internal messaging, use an event bus library.)

Comment: @GabeSechan Thanks for explanation

Answer (score 0):

If you need to pass some data between two activities you should use Intent for this:

```
class ActivityA extends AppCompatActivity {
    ...

    void startActivityB(String code) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
        i.putExtra("code", code);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}


class ActivityB extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
        String code = getIntent().getStringExtra("code");
    }
}
```

For more details look at official documentation [Start another activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity)

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to start target activity immediately to get the passed value, use ***SharedPreferences*** :

// set Weight

```
String weight = userWeight.getText().toString().trim();

SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putString("PrefWeightKey", weight );
editor.apply();
```

// get Weight

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String retrievedValue = sharedPreferences.getString("PrefWeightKey", "");
```

---

**else use *Intent***:

// set Weight

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Weight.this, Main_Interface.class);
intent.putExtra("PrefWeightKey", weight);
startActivity(intent);
```

// get Weight

```
String retrievedValue = getIntent().getStringExtra("PrefWeightKey");
```